# Log-Linear Dependent Variable Ratio beyond 1: how to interpret regressors

Tags: regression, odds-ratio, ratio, log-linear

I do run a regression model with a dependent variable = ratio calculated G=y/x which provides values between 0 - 9 for extreme cases. 
I use a log-linear model for my calculus with various continuous but also dummy variables (G=ratio).
    ln(G)=a + bX + cD + e
X continuous
D dummy

Interpreting influence of D (switching from 1 to 0) = 100*exp(-c-1/2v)-1 (v=standard error ^2) [Kennedy 81].

Is it correct to state: "I the dummy is switched from 1 to 0 my outcome ratio changes by x%" (ceteris paribus)? Thus if my ratio is for example 2 I get
           2+x% ?
           2*(1+x%)?
Thanks for helping me to solve my beginner issue.

Comment: There is an answer to your question here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-do-i-interpret-a-regression-model-when-some-variables-are-log-transformed/